# Unpacking NumberForm expressions

Tags: evaluation

Given a `NumberForm` expression, e.g.:

```
NumberForm[N[Pi], 10]
```

How does one get the underlying numerical expression (short of applying `First`)? Applying `Normal` does not yield the desired result:

```
NumberForm[N[Pi], 10] // Normal // Head
```

still yields `NumberForm`.

According to the documentation `NumberForm` expressions affect printing, but not evaluation. This is however not true for pattern matching.

Comment: But what's the problem with applying `First`?

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider in parallel two NumberForm expressions:

```
  expr1 = NumberForm[N[Pi], 10]
  expr2 = NumberForm[N[Pi], {3, 2}]
```

and let us look at their TreeForms:

```
  Row[{TreeForm[expr1, ImageSize -> 300], Spacer[20], 
  TreeForm[expr2, ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

giving this:

[image]

One can see now that in the both cases the number itself has the tree coordinate {1}:

```
 expr1[[1]]
expr2[[1]]

(*  3.14159
    3.14159   *)
```

Further, it is, indeed, the real number:

```
expr1[[1]] // Head

(*  Real  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you want a function like `Normal` that converts all `NumberForm` expressions to their plain numeric form.  This can be done with replacement.

```
expr = {NumberForm[N@Pi, 3], N@E, NumberForm[N@Degree, {1, 5}]}
```

> ```
> {3.14, 2.71828, 0.02000}
> ```

```
expr /. NumberForm[n_, ___] :> n
```

> ```
> {3.14159, 2.71828, 0.0174533}
> ```

To catch most number formatting wrappers we may use:

```
numberNormal = # /.
    {(AccountingForm | BaseForm | EngineeringForm | NumberForm | PaddedForm | 
         ScientificForm)[n_, ___] :> n} &;
```

Now:

```
{NumberForm[N@Pi, 3], BaseForm[N@E, 2], ScientificForm[N@Degree]} // numberNormal
```

> ```
> {3.14159, 2.71828, 0.0174533}
> ```